# How to rewrite the procedure correctly? I want to delete the old data from 4 months

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

My table name is ARBITER and one of the columns is CREATE_DATE. I want to delete the data older than  4 months.

How to rewrite the procedure correctly? So I have written this:

```
procedure RemoveOldData(CREATE_DATE) as 
BEGIN 
   delete from ARBITER 
   where trunc(sysdate) < add_months(trunc(sysdate),-4); 
END;
```

but i got this error

> Error(91): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following: begin end function pragma procedure

Comment: So does your table have a metadata column which stores the date when the record was created (or last updated)?

Comment: I have a table that stores when it was created (CRATE_DATE)
And I need according to this table to write a procedure that distinguishes everything that sleeps more than 4 months

Comment: What are the columns of create_date

Comment: Please provide some sample starting data and a demonstration of the expected output.

Comment: Name table is ARBITER
and one of the columns is CREATE_DATE
now i rewriteto this:


  procedure RemoveOldData(ARBITER  in varchar2)
as
BEGIN
  delete from ARBITER  
  where trunc(sysdate)  < add_months(trunc(sysdate),-4);

END;

but i got this error - 
Error(91): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     begin end function pragma procedure

Can you help me please ?

Comment: A procedure parameter (like `create_date` in your example) needs a datatype (`date`, `number`, `varchar2` etc). This is missing in your example.

Answer (score 2):

This procedure will produce the specific outcome you require:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE RemoveOldData IS
BEGIN
     delete from ARBITER 
     where create_date < add_months(trunc(sysdate),-4);
END;
/
```

Here is [a LiveSQL demo (OTN account required)](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/f5vj8vzy7yx7rjsqp8xo8wo71).

The problem is what you intend with this parameter

```
PROCEDURE RemoveOldData (ARBITER in varchar2)
```

Is that supposed to be a cut-off date? A table name?

Comment: This should be a field within a table

Comment: When I changed what you wrote you write to me:
Error(85,1): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following:     ( ; is with authid as cluster order using external    deterministic parallel_enable pipelined result_cache    accessible The symbol ";" was substituted for "BEGIN" to continue.

Comment: I have information in the app that I have to delete everything that sleeps more than 4 months. I have many columns of information that I have to delete using the date.(ARBITOR is one of many tables)
I'm sorry if it's clear enough I'm new at work and put me on the data team and I still do not know everything here

Comment: ok Thanks.
and sorry if thats not  clear enough Im new in the DB

Comment: @M.Ofek - so have you got the answer you need? If not, please clarify your question. If yes, please consider upvoting and/or accepting an answer. Accepted answers improve StackOverflow as a resource for future Seekers.

Comment: At the moment I have not yet been able to solve the problem,
I removed the varchar2 Because I have a lot of lines to delete and it does not fit. Now if I add more:    end;
After receiving I wrote one, It compiles
but now i need to write thats procedure on 1 line for add and test it but its not work i dont write it good

Comment: We can only solve problems as well as you can explain them. The easiest way to do that is to post some sample data and expected output. I may already have suggested you that. Post your code too.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you may use `months_between` function(if exactly period of four months should be included, add an equality sign before 4 also) :

```
PROCEDURE RemoveOldData 
BEGIN
     delete arbiter where months_between(trunc(sysdate),create_date)>=4;
END;
/
```

Answer (score -1):

```
create or replace procedure RemoveOldData(CREATE_DATE  in varchar2)
as
begin
delete from CREATE_DATE 
where trunc(sysdate)  < add_months(trunc(sysdate),-4);
exception
WHEN OTHERS THEN
   raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);

end;

/
```

Comment: Your original answer was a reasonable guess at what the OP wanted. Your edit mars that by reverting to their flawed logic ( `5 < (5-4)` can never be true) and adding some unhelpful error handling.

Comment: Error(91): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "end-of-file" when expecting one of the following:     begin end function pragma procedure 
That's the comment I got

Comment: I'm afraid this procedure doesn't make any sense. The parameter `CREATE_DATE`, which is not even a date, has the same name as a database table? And when is `trunc(sysdate)` ever going to be four months ago? And the exception handler is just bizarre.

Comment: @williamrobertson - to be fair this is a response to an earlier version of the question. I have edited the question as and when the OP provided more detail.